Drag and Drop not working after updating Jetpack Compose BOM
My drag events seem to drop from the drag event listeners after the first  .dragAndDropTarget() is triggered.
This behavior happened after updating JetpackCompose BOM from "2024.02.00" to "2024.09.00". I believe it's Material3's package versioning going from 1.2.1 -> 1.3.0 which is causing the issue.
Is this a me problem, or a library problem? I viewed their issue tracker but couldn't find any up-to-date bugs reporting this. Only this old post
Buggy behavior after update here
Working version with Material3 v.1.2.1 here.
//Sample code, created new project
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            DragDropTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val list = listOf("Box A", "Box B", "Box C", "Box D")
    var enteredBox by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
    var offSetPosition by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    var dragStartPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var dragOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val dragAndDropPayload by remember { mutableStateOf("PAYLOAD") }

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        color = Color.LightGray
    ) {
        Column {
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(55.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .dragAndDropSource {

                        detectTapGestures(
                            onPress = {

                                startTransfer(
                                    DragAndDropTransferData(
                                        ClipData(
                                            "test",
                                            arrayOf("MimTypes stuff"),
                                            ClipData.Item("N/A")
                                        ),
                                        localState = dragAndDropPayload,
                                    ),
                                )
                            },
                        )
                    },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ){
                Text("DRAG ME", color = Color.White)
            }

            Row(
                modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(0.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ){
                Text("BOM v 2024.08.00 works", color = Color(0xFF0CC584))
            }
            Row(
                modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ){
                Text("BOM v 2024.09.00 no bueno", color = Color.Red)
            }
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = modifier
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
                    .clipToBounds()
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .offset {
                        IntOffset(
                            0,
                            offSetPosition
                                .toInt()
                                .div(4)
                        )
                    }
            ) {
                list.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                    Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        modifier = modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(50.dp)
                            .background(
                                if (enteredBox == index) Color(0xFF0CC584) else Color(0xFF151F38)
                            )
                            .dragAndDropTarget(
                                shouldStartDragAndDrop = { true },
                                target = object : DragAndDropTarget {

                                    override fun onStarted(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onStarted(event)
                                        Log.d("D&D", "started $event")
                                        dragStartPosition = event.toAndroidDragEvent().y
                                    }

                                    override fun onMoved(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onMoved(event)
                                        val dragPosition = event.toAndroidDragEvent().y
                                        dragOffset = dragStartPosition - dragPosition
                                        offSetPosition = dragOffset
                                    }

                                    override fun onDrop(event: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
                                        Log.d("D&D", "drop $event")
                                        enteredBox = null
                                        offSetPosition = 0f
                                        return true
                                    }

                                    override fun onEntered(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onEntered(event)
                                        Log.d("D&D", "entered $event")
                                        enteredBox = index

                                    }

                                    override fun onExited(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onExited(event)
                                        Log.d("D&D", "exited $event")
                                        enteredBox = null
                                    }

                                    override fun onEnded(event: DragAndDropEvent) {
                                        super.onEnded(event)
                                        Log.d("D&D", "ended $event")

                                        enteredBox = null
                                        offSetPosition = 0f

                                    }
                                }
                            )
                    ){
                        Text(title.uppercase(), color = if(index == enteredBox) Color.Black else Color.White)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

